# Running Total with Blank Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a running total but have the formula keep a blank cell if there is no data or data yet to be entered while still keeping the total going. So it is a bank balance budget for a girl scout troop. We need to put in explanations for some deposits and withdrawals so I would like the bank balance to remain blank in those areas (IE cell B2 girl 1 dues paid x, B3 girl two camp trip paid x, B4 girl 5 cookies paid x, then B5 total deposit). Cell B lists the description which will also list item by item different items purchased or deposited (as above) so next to these items there is a blank cell for the deposit or withdrawal. Cell C is Deposits, Cell D is withdrawals and Cell E is the running bank balance. 
I need it to allow future additions without errors as I was facing before this current formula. I am using a IF(AND(ISBLANK(C2), ISBLANK(D2), "", C2+D2+E1)). This worked until it got down the the deposits that had blank cells for the descriptions of who paid what. It is not pulling the balance from the previous running total. How do I accomplish that with also allowing blank cells?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1426100/edit) to provide sample data? You can upload screenshots to imgur.com and link to them

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm understanding your description. If so, I think you can do this using the offset function.

```
=SUM($C2:$D2)+IF(ISNUMBER(OFFSET($E2,-1,0)),OFFSET($E2,-1,0),0)
```

See the sample worksheet image below.

Just copy this formula down column E as far as your data goes. 
Or, better yet, convert the range to a table, and use a calculated column, which does the work of replicating the formula for you.

[image: sample worksheet]
[image: sample worksheet with table]